# Converter is called twice, second time with null value

Tags: xaml, converters, maui, .net-maui

I am writing a MAUI app. I am trying to use a converter. But for some reason, the converter is called twice, and that makes the app crash. Here is the code:

xaml:

```
                    <Picker Title="Choose Tile Thickness..."
                        ItemsSource="{Binding TileThicknessesMetric}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTileThickness}"
                        IsVisible="{Binding SelectedUnit, Converter={converters:SelectedUnitToBoolShowMetricConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Style="{StaticResource PickerStyle}"
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Converter:

```
class SelectedUnitToBoolShowMetricConverter : IValueConverter, IMarkupExtension
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Unit)value).Code == UnitCode.Metric;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

As I mentioned, Convert() is called twice, and the second time value is null, which causes a null reference exception. I cannot figure out why it is called the second time.
The same code works as expected in a Xamarin.Forms app.

Comment: why don't you test for null to avoid the crash?

Comment: @Jason Because the converter should do its work. If should return an appropriate result. I can bypass the conversion, but then it is not possible to determine how the UI should look...

Comment: yes, it should "return an appropriate value" when it is passed a null input.  It is your responsibility to make that happen

Comment: @Jason But null is not a value that can be converted into something reasonable. Null should never happen.

Comment: but it **is happening**.  You could spend 2 minutes fixing the problem and move on, or you can waste time arguing about how this **shouldn't** happen even though it clearly is

Comment: @Jason I could make this patch if there was a way to convert null into something, but there isn't. Null is not a legitimate value. That is why I need to understand the root cause... The converter should not return any random result, but the right result.

Comment: @Jason Never mind, I just got rid of the converters at all, and replaced them with additional properties, using [AlsoNotifyChangeFor(nameof(ShowStandard))] attribute on the SelectedUnit property.

Comment: Its entirely possible, perhaps even likely, that converter call with null is irrelevant. Perhaps xamarin calls it when it has some element that is not yet initialized. Or while some UI is going away. Add code that when null is seen, returns some default value. Your testing should reveal whether there is any situation this "actually matters". Sounds like you have a repeatable test case already. Given that, should not take long to identify the UI element that is causing the null, and determine whether the returned value is actually seen anywhere.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for your input. Yes, I know what element is causing the problem. But I don't understand why on that very element the converter is called twice, first time with the expected value, and the second time with null. The default value would not do, as the the actual value matters.

Comment: *"The default value would not do, as the the actual value matters."* You've made that clear. What you didn't do, based on what you said and didn't say, is **test** whether the result of that second call *actually appeared in the UI*. My point is that your assumption that the value returned by the null call "matters" *might* be incorrect, for the reasons I mentioned. Without testing, you'll never know. Its moot now; just FYI for the future.